# Subclassing NSComboBox to display NSMenu on PopUp

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want an editable control similar to `NSComboBox`, which have the autocomplete capabilities of `NSComboBox` but the problem with combo box is that the list of values can only be text values. Whereas, I want, when the arrow button of combo box is pressed, it should display a NSMenu (so that I can display icons in front of the text and also can have separator NSMenuItem as one of the items in `NSMenu`).

So, I was planning to subclass `NSComboBox` such that the original list popup of `NSComboBox` is suppressed and instead of that an `NSMenu` is displayed.

But I have no idea where to start with.

Firstly, I am unable to suppress the default popup.
Second, there is no notification for the button press of the combo box, so that I can display my NSMenu.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I can think of would be to have a look at `NSControlTextEditingDelegate`. It declares a delegate method:

`- (NSArray *)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)index`

Use it in the delegate of a NSTextField for achieving your autocompletion needs and build the dropdown button yourself. A NSButton with an image plus a line of code for displaying your menu should do it.

Comment: I have already moved on with the sub-classing option. By **sub-classing the NSComboBox** to **handle the mouseDown event** and checking if the user has clicked on button area or textField area. If the user clicked on the button area an NSMenu is displayed. And for auto-completion, the auto-complete list is populated using the titles of the menuItems in the menu.

Comment: you are a genius @rsharma